# Start deployd server

Tags: deployd

Here's how I'm told I should get started with deployd:

```
$ mkdir deploydapps
$ cd deploydapps
$ dpd create helloworld
$ cd helloworld
$ dpd
```

I can do the above no problems. However, here's where I'm stumbling.

The instructions say the deployd server starts and it also opens a dpd shell in the console like this:

```
$ dpd
starting deployd v 7.0.0
listening on port 4800
type help for a list of commands
dpd >
```

However, here's what happens for me:

```
$ dpd
starting deployd v0.7.0...
$
```

For some reason it's daemonizing. **How do I stop it daemonizing? How am I supposed to know what port it's listening on?**

More worryingly, the server doesn't actually seem to start if I specify a port:

```
$ dpd --port 7777
```

I visit `0.0.0.0:7777` and `localhost:7777` and both give me a

`This web page is not available`

**Why is this happening?**

Comment: Could you solve this ? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: Sorry friend, I used webrick instead. If you want to learn ruby on rails it's a good server to use

Comment: It happened to me when I created package.json file next to app.dpd file. Once I deleted package.json file everything was OK - server started as usual

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll get some hints from

```
DEBUG=* dpd
```

This shows traces including environment variables while dpd starts itself.

Comment: @Esteban you can just type `$ DEBUG=* dpd` instead of `$ dpd`.
Then, you should be able to see more detailed information while deployd is launching.